# Emulador do Android carrega mas dá erro

Tags: android, android-studio

Este é o erro que dá depois de ficar minutos carregando

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: C:\Users\Reinaldo.android\avd\3.7_WVGA_Nexus_One_API_25.avd/userdata.img

Answer (score 0):

Você devia receber isso como um warning apenas da primeira vez que iniciou o simulador, se não for o caso, exclua a AVD e crie outra.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895124/emulator-emulator-error-missing-initial-data-partition-file